# git: what is dirty git version?

Tags: git, version

I have just compiled the latest version of git which was downloaded in the following way:

```bash
git clone --branch v2.36.1 https://github.com/git/git local_destination_directory
```

Once git was compiled and installed, I have checked its version and got the following:

```bash
$ git --version
git version 2.36.1.dirty
```

Could you please let me know what `dirty` means in the git version suffix?

Comment: Usually that indicates that your tree wasn't clean when you built it. The suffix seems to be constructed here: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/GIT-VERSION-GEN

Comment: @JoachimSauer I have cloned git source code into a new directory (as described in my question). Could you, please, clarify how it could happen that the _"tree was't clean"_? Was it not clean in the git repository? Thank you!

Comment: I have installed `git-2.36.0` and this version is not dirty (_"git version 2.36.0"_). Random guess hypothesis: if the last digit (i.e. `0`) is even then the version is clean, otherwise it is "dirty".